# How to use .NET Web Deployment Projects to REMOVE a web.config section

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, web-deployment

I use a Web Deployment Project to build my release package and replace specific sections of my web.config file. I configure the original web.config file with values used to debug, AppSettings for example. And then I have a file called AppSettings.Release.config and I use the following to build the release package:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <WebConfigReplacementFiles Include="Config\AppSettings.Release.config">
        <Section>appSettings</Section>
    </WebConfigReplacementFiles>
    <WebConfigReplacementFiles Include="Config\Compilation.Release.config">
        <Section>system.web/compilation</Section>
    </WebConfigReplacementFiles>
    <WebConfigReplacementFiles Include="Config\CustomErrors.Release.config">
        <Section>system.web/customErrors</Section>
    </WebConfigReplacementFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

I also have a connection string specified for debugging as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLConnectionString"
         connectionString="Server=[server name]Database=[database name];Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am migrating to Windows Azure and I would like to use the portal interface to manage my connection strings - not the web.config file. So in the portal, I added an entry for my website under connection strings named "SQLConnectionString" with the correct production string.

My problem is, I want to use the deployment project to completely REMOVE the `<connectionStrings>` element from my web.config file. How do I do that?

Note: I tried simply doing the section replacement with an empty element and I got the following error:

web.config(25): error WDP00001: section connectionStrings in "web.config" has 1 element but "Config\ConnectionStrings.Release.config" has 0 elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder have you ever checked the official [MSDN docmentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx). And whether you have tried the following in your connectionstrings.release.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
</connectionStrings>
```

According to the documentation this must remove all the entries.

Comment: I'm not using web.config transforms. I'm using the other method with Web Deployment Projects. XML transforms are done by having multiple web.config files that are merged automatically.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you are talking about, or can't get it into my mind without a proper reference. But I am sure that if you dig deeper in the documentation on the method you use, you will find something similar!